# Github and @slabia slabia – user_session.country_change Country problem

Tags: github, heroku

I try today to deploy in Heroku and there is a problem with the deploy, but more strange i was in GitHub and under the security log I found this:

– user_session.country_change
The country changed from your previous session
185.99.3.32 Bosnia and Herzegovina 21 hours ago

Anybody know how the country was changed and how to set up it back?

Thank you very much